# ¿Cómo resaltar las palabras de mi array a colores diferentes pero que solo se resalten si el usuario insertar tal palabra textare?

Tags: javascript, array

Osea quiero que los textos de mi array se resalten a un color(El rojo bajo), pero quiero que se resalten cuando el usuario de la pagina escriba tal palabra en un textArea. En pocas palabras que se resalten las syntaxis ya escritas en mi array.

```
var syntax = [
           alerta: #E73F3F,
           consola: #BEE73F,
           voz: #BEE73F
       ];
var palabras = {"alerta", "consola", "voz"};
var TextoArea = document.querySelector(".Syntax");
while(true){
       if(TextoArea.value == palabras[0,3]){
          var code = document.createElement("code");
          if(code.innerHTML == palabras[0]){code.style.color=syntax[0]};
          if(code.innerHTML == palabras[1]){code.style.color=syntax[1]};
          if(code.innerHTML == palabras[3]){code.style.color=syntax[3]};                
      }
    }
```

Alguien me puede ayudar?

A lo que me refiero con esto esque quiero que el JavaScript detecte en todo momento lo que vaya a escribir un usuario en el textArea, si el JavaScript detecta que si escribe una variable de mi array "**palabras**" haga que se cree un "elemento Code" y que lo cambie de color segun la palabra que haya escrito en el textArea y el Code se traslade al textArea.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: debes meter etiquetas html donde encuntres la pablara ingresandole una clase donde pones el color ----hola <span class="colorear">mundo</span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consigna es fácil de entender, pero no es tan fácil de implementar. Un elemento `textarea` no puede mostrar texto con diferentes formatos, solo texto plano. Lo que se necesita es un `div` editable. Ejemplo:

```
<div contenteditable="true">El texto <span style="color:#ff0000">resaltado</span>.</div>
```

Notar el atributo `contenteditable` que hace que el `div` sea editable.

Tu trabajo sería el siguiente:

- Definir el estilo principal del `div`.
- Definir el estilo de las palabras resaltadas.
- Con javascript: chequear el `div` palabra por palabra mientras el usuario escribe y en caso de encontrar una reemplazarla por el código resaltado (algo como `<span class="resaltado">palabra</span>` por ejemplo). Esto se puede hacer de varias maneras, quizás buscando palabras completas (espacio-palabra-espacio) o por expresiones regulares...pero eso ya es tema para otra pregunta.

Suerte.